# Numerical solutions to the 3D wave equation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, acoustics, computational-physics, algorithms

I am doing a research to explore the existing numerical schemes that are used to solve the $3$D wave equation.

The standard form of the problem in $3$ dimensional setting is : $$\Delta u= \frac{1}{c^2} u_{tt}\ ,\ c\text{ is constant}$$
and $ u: \mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ , with initial conditions : 
$u(x,0)= f(x)\ ,\ u_t(x,0)= g(x)$ , for arbitrary density functions $f, g: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (though generally compactly supported)

I am developing a new scheme that should be practical in many settings, now I need to compare it to other schemes to check what is the most efficient.

Are schemes based on the finite elements method the only schemes used ? or is there anything else?

Comment: No, FEM is not the only way to go. Take a look at PINNs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics-informed_neural_networks). If you know some Python, you can straight import deepxde for some deep learning on PDEs (https://deepxde.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Most straight-forward would be [Finite Difference methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Relation_with_derivatives), e.g. forward or backward Euler.

Comment: I also find it curious that you are trying to develop a new scheme for solving a PDE without knowing common methods to solve the PDE. I suspect that you should probably do your review before new model development, otherwise you can end up re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I believe that @KyleKanos is right. First of all the Finite-Difference Time-Domain method seems to be (to my knowledge) the easiest (in the sense that it is the most straight forward one) of the methods in use at the moment. Other methods are Finite-Elements (as you mentioned) and Boundary-Elements. I am not an expert on numerical/computational acoustics but I believe you could also have a look at Spectral-Methods. They may just end up being different formulations of the other methods though. Additionally, I believe there's FEM and BEM methods for the time-domain (transient responses).

Comment: Plus, there are  time domain Fourier transform  and Fourier series variable separation methods, and probably methods based on Green's function associated to the wave equation, which could overlap sometimes with the Fourier series. Maybe these are called spectral methods, but I am not sure about the terminology. However, the finite element methods could start as spectral methods, where the Hilbert basis is made of finite element functions.